# Find Window's coordinates in tkinter

Tags: python, windows, canvas, tkinter

I'm working on a project where I have to zoom in an image, I have a program but when I zoom, the focus of the zoom depends on the canvas coordinates and not the current window coordinates so the zoom is not centered on the window.

```
def zoomer(self,event):
    if (event.delta > 0):
        self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 1.1, 1.1)
    elif (event.delta < 0):
        self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 0.9, 0.9)
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))
```

I would like to replace "event.x" and "event.y" with window coordinates and not canvas one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace all the `event.x` by `event.x_root` and `event.y` by `event.y_root` and you will have window coordinates .

Comment: You're welcome. I found the information here: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-handlers.html